# Arxiv rejection of preprints

Tags: arxiv, rejection, preprint

Following ArXiv rules I contacted with an well-known expert in thermodynamics (he is author of a known monograph) we discussed my work during several days and finally he endorsed me. When my work was ready to appear a moderator removed it, alluding to technical problems with my submission (a embedded font problem), although more latter moderators asked me personal and even economic questions! I never answer such questions and forgot the whole issue

The paper is accessible in my page at [academia.edu](http://www.academia.edu/2216383/Non-redundant_and_natural_variables_definition_of_heat_valid_for_open_systems)

I have participated in an Essay Contest with another work, and it has been selected as one of the finalists. It is cited [here](http://fqxi.org/community) together other three finalist essays.

I submitted this new work to ArXiV, it has been removed and I received the next response:

> Your submission has been removed upon a notice from our moderators, who 
>   determined it to be inappropriate for arXiv. Please find another forum.
>
> For more information on our moderation policies see:
>
> http: //arxiv. org/help/moderation
>
> --
>   arXiv moderation

ArXiv already archives several essays submitted to the same Essay contest, such as 1209.0023, 1209.1257, 1211.1917, 1210.3575

Therefore it is not a problem with the Contest or with the format. Notice that only one of above four has been selected as finalist.

According to the moderation policy I cannot ask to moderators about the details on their decision. The excuse is that "*moderators are not referees*", but this looks a bit childish, because it seems that they are accepting that moderators cannot sustain logically the decisions that they take about others' work.

Would I write to the advisory committee chair? Would I take some other action?

EDIT: Finally the first work rejected by Arxiv mods was published in the International Journal of Thermodynamics. I no longer care about ArXiv.

Comment: What's the relationship between the first and the second paper? At first glance, it seems like two different issues (which would be better in two different questions then).

Comment: Is this on scope ? this seems to be an arxiv specific issue.

Comment: @Suresh: I think we've had many questions about arXiv here, so I wouldn't classify it as off-topic just because of that.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Actually most arxiv-related questions are about "best practices", which seem reasonable. There is one specific question about the arxiv endorsement policy which is akin to this one, and that was fine. So I guess this might be ok as well. I thought it might be off-scope because it's asking a question that only an arxiv moderator can really answer.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset: The only relation is that both were rejected without any clear reason.

Comment: @Suresh: The moderation policy explicitly says that moderators will not answer. I am asking here for advice on what actions to take (if any). Yes I read the question about endorsement, but I am already endorsed.

Comment: @Suresh: I agree that this particular question seems to be only answerable by "contact the moderators". Let's see how it goes.

Comment: @juanrga: At the [link you put](http://arxiv.org/help/moderation), there is: "If you disagree with a moderation decision, you should submit an appeal that explains clearly and succinctly what your arguments are." Have you submitted an appeal yet? I don't see where it's written that the moderators won't answer.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset: I did not submit because a bit below says "The moderators are not referees and do not provide detailed feedback on submissions. Administrators thus cannot provide detailed feedback regarding submissions deemed inappropriate, and will not enter into extended discussion regarding submissions."

Comment: When you say personal and economic questions, do you mean asking about potential conflicts of interests?

Comment: A more direct link to the second paper is http://fqxi.org/community/forum/topic/1356

Comment: @DanielEShub: No.

Comment: arXiv.org moderators have often been jerks, in my experience. They revoked my endorsement status after I resubmitted a previously rejected article with a few modifications. It seems they'd give a warning first.

Comment: Check out: http://www.archivefreedom.org/

Comment: Just for the record: there is a difference between "we don't answer" and "we do not give detailed feedback" / "we do not enter extended discussion about the topic". Actually, no reasonable moderation policy would support extended discussions.

Comment: Congratulations on trancending the need for arXiv by publishing in one of the journals listed at https://scholarlyoa.com/2013/01/15/open-access-publisher-launches-with-355-new-journals/

Comment: @Tobias-kildetoft. My work was published on International Journal of Thermodynamics. Congratulations to you by linking to a blog entry about the Academic and Scientific Publishing, which publishes a fake journal with a different name "International Research Journal of Thermodynamics" http://www.acascipub.com/Journals.php

Comment: No, the name of the predatory journal exactly matches the name you give here, as can be seen on the list I linked.

Comment: @Tobias-kildetoft. No. The blog article you gave is about "Academic and Scientific Publishing" which publishes a predatory journal (with a slightly different title) as can be seen on the list they maintain. Also pretending that two journals are the same because have the same title reflects your ignorance of those issues. Fraudulent publishers duplicate the titles of legit journals...

Comment: @Tobias-kildetoft. This is the legit Journal where I published (http://dergipark.ulakbim.gov.tr/eoguijt//index). This is a fake journal with the same title (http://iosrd.org/journals/index.php/ijth/index) published by one of those fraudulent publishers mentioned in the blog. Now accept your mistake and move on.

Answer (score 21):

As said in the comments, the situation seems to be different for each of your papers. The font problem is understandable, but it's hard to see what you mean by "personal and even economic questions". However, if you didn't answer the questions, it's not surprising that your paper was not published in arXiv.

Concerning the essay, I quote from the [FAQ](http://arxiv.org/help/moderation), "arXiv accepts only submissions in the form of an article that would be refereeable by a conventional publication venue.", and in particular, " This excludes [...] papers that contain inflammatory or fictitious content, papers that use highly dramatic and mis-representative titles/abstracts/introductions". I'm in no position to scientifically judge the content of your essay, but at first glance, it seems quite provocative (assumptions that are not fundamental).

If you believe that your essay is "refereeable by a conventional publication venue", then the moderation appeal is there for this. Although the moderators do not have to motivate their decision as a reviewer would do, by bringing sufficient support that your paper meets the criteria required by arXiv (in particular by demonstrating that it doesn't fit in any of the categories listed under "inappropriate format", the fact that other essays have been published in the past is not really relevant, you would have to show the quality of your content on its own).

In general, arXiv moderators are human moderators, and it could be the case that the rejection of your paper was a mistake. However, keep in mind that publishing in arXiv is not a granted right, and that "arXiv reserves the right to reject or reclassify any submission".

Comment: The theme for this Essay Contest is: [Questioning the Foundations: Which of Our Basic Physical assumptions are Wrong?](http://fqxi.org/community/essay) and as said at least 4 essays are archived in ArXiv. Yes you are right that ArXiv reserves the right. I am asking for advice about possible actions to take.

Comment: Gather the info, submit an appeal. If this appeal is rejected, only then you can try to contact the advisory committee chair. That's the only action you can take at this step (or just put your paper somewhere else).

Comment: @juanrga Do you have any update on the issue?

Comment: @user13107 Finally, my work was published in the International Journal of Thermodynamics. I contacted a last time with Arxiv mods commenting them that the paper they rejected without any explanation was published. I no longer am interested in so biased site.

Answer (score -6):

Of course, arXiv.org is the best place to go without peer-review. Many papers that appear in arXiv are of the highest quality. Be polite with moderators, never challenge them as they have the right to reject any paper without any explanation. Try to appeal. If this does not help, address this issue to Chair. If again no result, go to vixra.org and publish your paper over there without headache. Vixra.org is the best solution when you unable to publish it in arxiv.org.

Comment: Publishing on Vixra is almost surely a mistake, if one wants to ever be taken seriously by professionals, etc.

Comment: viXra is a legitimate reaction to arXiv's tendency in taking itself too seriously. arXiv moderators say that they are not reviewers (since they are not specialists in the field) but still act as reviewers when refusing papers as "not being interesting enough", that's hypocrisy.

Answer (score -9):

If arxiv rejects your paper, go to vixra.org. You can also publish it in researchgate.net Don't get upset and try to be fast with your publication. Remember, any submission you've made is a potential leak of your idea!

Comment: The idea that someone is going to steal a paper rejected from the arXiv is on the far side of paranoid.

Comment: @Corvus Why? If it is rejected for font issues then it seems just as likely as any other unpublished paper to be stolen.

Comment: @dorothy, do you know of a single case where a moderator at the arXiv has stolen a rejected paper?

Comment: @Corvus No. But then I don't actually know of any cases where a paper was rejected from the arXiv at all so it's not clear what to draw from that. I do know of a case where something actually published on the arXiv was stolen and then published somewhere prestigious (and is still published there) which seems even more surprising.

Comment: Read about Grisha Perelman and then you will be able to understand why any submission is a potential leak.

Comment: The chances that an idea is worth stealing in the first place are much smaller than the author may often suspect, especially when worrying about such a thing... especially if the arXiv.org moderators reject the paper entirely. Again, as in a comment of mine to another answer to this question, if you do have hope of being taken seriously by professionals, editing and resubmitting to arXiv, ... not vixra or other similar.

Comment: @Paul Garrett, Let me clarify... I agree that if you have choice between arxiv and vixra, then arxiv is definitely in priority. However, if it has been rejected from arxiv, then the good choice is vixra. Secondly, the chances that the new idea can be published by "independent" researchers is much higher than one may expect (I am also a professional experienced researcher with many publications in peer review journals). Please read about Grigori Perelman who proved the Poincaré Conjecture if you don't believe about leak in science.

Comment: @user32476 Perelman was quite well known before his paper, or I do not think that a hard to read/follow paper would have been quite that a success in the community. And the "leak" was not that - the story is a bit more intricate in that, as far as I understand, it was claimed that the paper had gaps which had been filled. The discussion is now what is a gap, and what is simply something that the reader has not understood that the author did? So, Perelman does not quite qualify as a counterexample.